# Move Div/Header Along With Page Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to Move a Div/Header of my Page along with page. i.e., the header follows page up/down. Here is a website example that i am trying to do. As from the website we can notice that the top header moves up/down along with page scroll.

http://www.topix.com/forum/med/dermatology/T2966QF431OFQNCQG

https://in.answers.yahoo.com/;_ylt=Au8NphoCl4T3K3_yv8lHbr_lHwx.

Comment: give it `position:fixed;`

Comment: Try this jquery plugin [ScrollToFixed](http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .headerClass
 {
   position: fixed;
 }
```

This is not moving with the scroll event. It is fixed position

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/3U2Ck/6/) Check this demo

Comment: his examples involve also a bit of JS, because those divs do not have always the fixed position...

Comment: scrollTop > AmountNeeded then add Position fixed.. If it is lesser remove this class